# Upgrading Spring Security breaks a project

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a template project I created long time ago. Project can be found on: [here](https://github.com/ivandejanovic/springdemo)

All the libraries have been updated to a new versions expect spring security. If you checkout master branch go to [localhost:8080/springdemo/index.htm](http://localhost:8080/springdemo/index.htm) application will redirect you to login page and once you enter demouser/demopass or userdemo/passdemo you will be logged in and redirected to index.htm.

Problem is when I update to Spring Security 4.2.3.RELEASE application does not work. This code is on spring-security-update branch. I tried a lot of online resources. Messed around with csrf token and disabled it for time being but was unable to get it to work.

Anybody has an idea why is spring security not working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of migration from version 3 to version 4. To make all this works you should do this:

1) in your `index.jsp` change form action from `action='/springdemo/j_spring_security_check'` to `action='/springdemo/login'`

2) in your `index.jsp` change input name from `name='j_username'` to `name='username'`, same for `name='j_password'` -> `name='password'`

3) in your index.jsp change logout url from `href="j_spring_security_logout"` to `href="logout"`

Worked for me. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. This all works while csrf token is disabled. Once I uncomment it in login.jsp and put it back on in applicationContext-security.xml logout does not work. Logout seems to need the csfr token. Thank again you given me a breakthrough.

Comment: @IvanDejanovic, yes acccording to spring documentation: _Adding CSRF will update the LogoutFilter to only use HTTP POST. This ensures that log out requires a CSRF token and that a malicious user cannot forcibly log out your users._ It means, that you need to use POST form for logout with csrf token in it similar to login functionality

Comment: Btw, ajax calls not working either. Csrf token requires

Comment: @IvanDejanovic, to fix ajax requests you can go through [this spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax). Hope it helps!

Comment: You might want to add links to the documentation which clearly explain what needs to be upgraded. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-logout